# accessing a path from an external text file

Tags: shell-script

I have a text file with the paths of certain log file which are named the same.

```
/inc/sync/result/debug_TFS16.log
/inc/async/result/debug_TFS16.log
/dec/sync/result/debug_TFS16.log
/dec/async/result/debug_TFS16.log
```

How can I pick the path one line at a time and use it to run another script that further manipulates the log file?

Comment: Please be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish. How are you trying to manipulate the log files? Do you even have write access to them? What does the other script do and can you provide an example of the code?

Comment: The logfile contains lots of useless info and the max value. I will be using grep to get the max value and pipe it out to another text file.

my issue is that, since the different log files are in different locations, i want to know how i can write a script to get the path, one line at a time and execute the grep to get max value.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're trying to read this log file *and* manipulate it at the same time? What sequence of events do you envision here?

Comment: @JeffSchaller<br>
ok this is exactly what i want done...
i run the script which goes to the text file which has the path to the log file:

/inc/sync/result/debug_TFS16.log<br/>

/inc/async/result/debug_TFS16.log<br/>

/dec/sync/result/debug_TFS16.log<br/>

/dec/async/result/debug_TFS16.log<br/>


then go to that path on line 1 and 

`grep "max_val" debug_TFS16.log > log1.txt`

then go to path on line 2 and 

`grep "max_val" debug_TFS16.log > log2.txt`

Comment: I'm sorry for  my post above, i'm very new to this and still learning how to format this.

Comment: The best thing to do is to [edit your post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/490048/edit) with the updates, so that they're not lost in the comments here.  Thank you!

Comment: If you can spell out the naming conventions for your files, that will help people understand your goal. Is "log1.txt" named because it's the results from the 1st line of the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe using a loop:

```
#! /bin/bash

COUNT=0

while read line 
do 

COUNT=`expr ${COUNT} + 1`

PATHIN=`dirname $line`
FILENAME=`cat $line | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'`

cd ${PATHIN}
grep "max_val" ${FILENAME} > Log_${COUNT}.log

done < input_file
```

You only must change input_file for name of file that have all data.

Answer (score 0):

The command you search for is `dirname`
for example for file:

```
/dec/async/result/debug_TFS16.log
```

if you execute

```
dirname /dec/async/result/debug_TFS16.log
```

you will get

```
/dec/async/result
```

Answer (score 0):

Using bash features to read the filenames into an array,

```
readarray -t list < input
for((i=0; i<${#list[@]}; i++))
do 
  grep max_val "${list[i]}" > log"$((i+1))".txt
done
```

This reads the filenames into the array variable `list`, then loops over the indexes of that array (in `i`) and runs the grep command on the corresponding filename and redirects the output to the desired log filename. Bash arrays are zero-indexed, so I add one to the array index to create the filename.

Answer (score 0):

You can step over each line in a file with a `while read` loop. Here's a sample file, called "samplefile.txt".

```
root@server :~$ cat samplefile.txt
line 1
line #2
line3
 line 4
#line5 shouldn't print
  # line 6 shouldn't print either
line 7 should print
```

If you want to add the ability to ignore lines starting with '#', you can add that into the command.

```
root@server :~$ while read line ; do echo -e "$line" | egrep -v '\s*^#'; done < samplefile.txt
line 1
line #2
line3
line 4
line 7 should print
```

Note that some lines started with a space, but the latter output didn't show that. That may or may not affect your scenario.